# Is it possible to include tag definitions within answers?

Tags: support, tags, answers

I want to know if it is possible to include tag definitions within answers so that a tooltip shows up with the definition on hover. This can be useful when using jargon to explain to some users what they need to do, or to help answer a question.

If it is possible, how do you do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "tag definition"? Every tag has its own info page: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info, e.g.

Comment: Ah, that's where the tag pages are. I trying to find them. I meant tooltips really, where you can rollover the tag and see a short definition, although a link to the tag info page would be just as useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include a nifty inline version of the tag like so:

```
[tag:objective-c]
```

This renders to [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), which gives you the tag wiki excerpt when you mouse over it. (Use `[meta-tag:tagname]` to point at tags on Meta rather than the main site).

You can also link to the tag's info page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion/info, e.g. A link at the bottom of the full description will display the excerpt:

[image]